# Efficient algorithm to determine range [a, b] of sin wave with interval

Tags: algorithm, math, range, intervals, trigonometry

I have a sine wave whose parameters I can determine (they are user-input). It's of the form y=a*sin(m*x + t)

I'd like to know whether anyone knows an efficient algorithm to figure out the range of y for a given interval which goes from [0, x] (x is again another input)

For example:

for y = sin(x) (i.e. a=1, t=0, m=1), for the interval [0, 4] I'd like an output like [1, -0.756802]

Please keep in mind, m and t can be anything. Thus, the y-curve does not have to start (or end) at 0 (or 1). It could start anywhere.

Also, please note that x will be discrete.

Any ideas?

PS: I'll use python for implementing the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since function `y(x) = a*sin(m*x + t)` is continuous, maximum will be either at one of the interval's ends or at the maximum inside interval, in this case `dy/dx` will be equal to zero.

So:
 1. Find values of y(x) at the ends of interval.
 2. Find out if dy/dx == a * m cos (mx + t) have zero(s) in interval, find out values of y(x) at the zero(s).
 3. Choose point where `y(x)` have maximum value

Answer (score 2):

If you have greater than one period then the result is just +/- a.

For less than one period you can evaluate y at the start/end points and then find any maxima between the start/end points by solving for `y' = 0`, i.e. `cos(m*x + t) = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are more or less the same. Thanks guys=)

I think I'd go with something like the following (note that I am renaming the variable I called "x" to "end". I had this "x" at the beginning which denoted the end of my interval on the X-axis):

1) Evaluate y at 0 and "end", use an if-block to assign the two values to the correct PRELIMINARY "min" and "max" of the range

2) Evaluate number of evolutions: "evolNr" = (m*end)/2Pi. If evolNr > 1, return [-a, a]

3) If evolNr < 1: First find the root of the derivative, which is at "firstRoot" = (1/2m)*Pi - phase + q * 1/m * Pi, where q = ceil(m/Pi * ((1/2m) * Pi - phase) ) --- this gives me the first root at some position x > 0. From then on I know that all other extremes are within firstRoot and "end", we have a new root every 1/m * Pi.

In code: for (a=firstRoot; a < end; a += 1/m*Pi) {Eval y at a, if > 0 its a maximum, update "max", otherwise update "min"}

return [min, max]

Comment: I provide full answer as a first one you marked other as answer?